# Python and C# HMAC SHA1 results are not Matching

Tags: python, c#, hmacsha1

```py
import hashlib
import hmac
import base64
import json


def make_digest(payload, api_key,api_secret):

    api_key = api_key.encode("ascii")
    api_secret = api_secret.encode("ascii")
    payload = payload.encode("ascii")

    # print(payload)
    k=b'%s&%s' % (api_key, api_secret)

    signature = hmac.new(
    key= k,
    msg=payload,
    digestmod=hashlib.sha1)

    signature_digest = signature.digest()

    return base64.b64encode(signature_digest)


api_key='somekey'
api_secret='somesecret'

payload1 = "{\"name\":\"somename\",\"filter_type\":\"somefilter\",\"filter_id\":\"1\",\"event_type\":\"some_event\",\"event_id\":\"1\",\"event_datetime\":\"2023-02-20T13:07:26.367367+00:00\",\"object_type\":\"sometype\",\"object_id\":\"2\",\"resources\":{\"respondent_id\":\"12\",\"recipient_id\":\"0\",\"survey_id\":\"12313\",\"user_id\":\"12312312313\",\"collector_id\":\"234234\"}}"


payload=json.loads(payload1)

payload=json.dumps(payload)
result = make_digest(payload,api_key,api_secret)
print(result)
result1 = make_digest(payload1,api_key,api_secret)
print(result1)
```

I am a dotnet dev, currently exporting a Python function to C# .net 6. I am not able to get the same output in C#.

```cs
public static string GetHash(string apiKey,string apiSecret, string payLoad)
{
    ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();

    byte[] apiSecretAscii = encoding.GetBytes(apiSecret);
    byte[] apiKeyAscii = encoding.GetBytes(apiKey);
    byte[] payLoadBytes = encoding.GetBytes(payLoad);
    byte[] hashBytes;
    var key = apiKeyAscii.Concat(encoding.GetBytes("&")).Concat(apiSecretAscii).ToArray();
    using (HMACSHA1 hash = new (key))
    {
        hashBytes = hash.ComputeHash(payLoadBytes);
    }

    return Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);
}
```

And calling this function like this

```cs
 var str = GetHash("somekey", "somesecret", "{\"name\":\"somename\",\"filter_type\":\"somefilter\",\"filter_id\":\"1\",\"event_type\":\"some_event\",\"event_id\":\"1\",\"event_datetime\":\"2023-02-20T13:07:26.367367+00:00\",\"object_type\":\"sometype\",\"object_id\":\"2\",\"resources\":{\"respondent_id\":\"12\",\"recipient_id\":\"0\",\"survey_id\":\"12313\",\"user_id\":\"12312312313\",\"collector_id\":\"234234\"}}");
            Console.WriteLine(str);
```

I have few questions regarding this:

1. I am not sure why the first print output of the Python code is not similar to second print output of the Python code. I want to match the first outcome of the Python code in the C# code. Basically this hash needs to be matched which I am getting from request header for the same request.
2. Is `json.dumps` in Python the equivalent of `NewtonSoft.Jsonconvert.SerializeObject()`?

Comment: what is the output that is correct?

Comment: `print(result)` is the correct one , matching with hash

Comment: well `payload1` and `payload` are not the same strings and thus have different hashes. when you hash in C# are you hashing the string from `payload` or `payload1`?

Comment: `payload1` . but its just a serialized string . no attribute change . `payload` is not a string in c#

Comment: `payload=json.dumps(payload, separators=[",",":"])` makes `payload` and `payload1` the same string if that helps

Comment: yeah . I added that and checked the hash. its same . but the point is without separators how this is possible to achieve in c# ? because bydefault serializeObject does that